# proving the Cartesian product itself

Tags: set-theory, proof-explanation

This is the so-called Cartesian Product of a and b as I understand it:

- ∀c (c ∈ a×b ↔ ∃x∃y (x∈a ∧ y∈b ∧ c=⟨x, y⟩)

I'm utterly new to proofs in mathematics. I've researched how to prove the Cartesian product, but all I can find are applications of it.

How do I go about proving that for any two sets a and b, there is a set of all ordered pairs ⟨x, y⟩ such that x ∈ a and y ∈ b?

The best I have amounts just to reiterations of what I'm trying to prove. Given it is relatively uninformative I imagine it can't be the total of what I'm asked to do:

- Assume c ∈ a×b. For this to be true, on pain of contradiction, c must
  be an ordered pair such that its first element, say x, is a member of
  a. Further, its second element, say y, must be a member of b.

  Assume it's false that c ∈ a×b. Then one of three things must be the
  case, on pain of contradiction. Either c isn't an ordered pair, or it
  is an ordered pair but its first element isn't a member of a or it is
  an ordered pair but its second element isn't a member of b.

  So, c ∈ a×b just in case c is an ordered pair whose first element is
  a member of a and its second element is a member of b.

Comment: To prove that such a set exists, you need a set-theoretic definition of pair $\langle x,y\rangle$. Different authors use different definitions, which are all equivalent in basically everything **except** the technical detail you are asking. Which one are you using?

Comment: The thing you've written is not the Cartesian product. It is a property that the Cartesian product satisfies. You don't have to prove the existance of Cartesian products because these are constructed explicitely and directly from ZF axioms. See Patrick's answer.

Comment: @Andrés: Shouldn't this be tagged under the elementary tag?

Comment: @Asaf Probably, but the answer made me decide otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

In the axiom system ZF, if we encode the ordered pair $\langle x, y \rangle$ (where $x \in X, y \in Y$) as $\{\{x\}, \{x,y\}\}$ (the Kuratowski definition), then we have $\langle x, y \rangle \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X \cup Y))$ (where $\mathcal{P}$ is the power-set). We then simply select an appropriate subset using the axiom schema of comprehension: namely, the subset such that a set is in the subset iff it is an ordered pair with first element in $X$ and second element in $Y$.

---

By the way, and completely tangentially, there's a lovely definition of the ordered pair due to Quine. (This serves to show you that "ordered pair" objects need not look at first glance anything like what you might expect them to look like; this particular definition happens to have some nice type-theoretic properties.)

Given a set $\mathbb{N}$ of the natural numbers, we may define the class-function $\phi$ which takes a set $X$ and increments every natural number in $X$, leaving the rest of $X$ unchanged.
Notice that $\phi$ has a left inverse: namely "decrement every natural number in $\phi(X)$, leaving the rest of $\phi(X)$ unchanged".

Then define $\langle A, B \rangle$ as $$\{ \phi(a): a \in A \} \cup \{ \phi(b) \cup \{0\} : b \in B \}$$
We can tell whether $r \in \langle A, B \rangle$ came from the $A$-component or from the $B$-component by seeing whether $0 \in r$: since $0 \in r$ if and only if $r = \phi(b) \cup \{0\}$ for some $b \in B$. (This is because $\phi(Y)$ can never contain $0$ for any set $Y$, since $\phi$ increments all natural numbers in $Y$ and since no natural number increments to $0$.)

To recover $b \in B$ from $r = \phi(b) \cup \{0\}$, just take $\phi^{-1}(r \setminus \{0\})$; to recover $a \in A$ from $r = \phi(a)$, just take $\phi^{-1}(r)$.